# Managed Package Extension to hold object translations

Tags: managed-package, limits, translation, translation-workbench

Our managed package finally has reached 10,000 files limit and now we cannot put it together anymore - Limit Exceeded exception (confirmed by SF support that we really cannot put more files and no way to increase this limit).

Analyzing number of files generated by each type of component, we've noticed that objectTranslation folder itself contain about 3,000 files (we are currently supporting 11 languages, and there will be more in the future).

Looks like in our case object translations artifact is a good candidate to be moved out of the main package - lots of file, no compile time dependencies etc. But when trying to create second package (as extension of the first one) we have noticed that there is no way to include objectTranslations separately. As I get, they are included implicitly when adding appropriate SObject to the package, which does not work for us (we want to keep schema in the main package).

Are there any other ways to allocate translations outside the main package, but still have them available for subscriber somehow? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to not spent time on moving translations from the package, because it is planned for Spring '19 release, to exclude them from counting for limit.